# How to convert multiple rows into single row in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in table as below:

[image: pre]

I have data as above in table. This table has many MMID M000071,M000073,....etc. screeningterm might vary for assets. Every MMID may have several dates.

I want output as below:

[image: after]

There are 20 thousands in the table. So I want to find an easy way to do this job.

Comment: re: *'So I want to find a easy way to do this job.'* - Use a variant array in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeeped give me a suggestion that use VBA.

So through several hours learning of Excel VBA, I have solved this problem and gain the answer that I want.

The code as below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sort()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim cursor As Long
    j = 2
    cursor = 2

    For j = 2 To 20150
X:      If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "A").Value = "" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "A").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "A").Value
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "H").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "D").Value
            Select Case Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B")
                Case "ACR"
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "B") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                Case "Microalbumin"
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "C") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                Case "eGFR"
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "D") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                Case "LDL_HDL_TotChol"
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "E") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                Case "HbA1C"
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "F") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                Case "UricAcid"
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "G") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
            End Select
        Else
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "A").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "A").Value Then
                If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "D").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "H").Value Then
                    Select Case Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B")
                        Case "ACR"
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "B") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                        Case "Microalbumin"
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "C") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                        Case "eGFR"
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "D") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                        Case "LDL_HDL_TotChol"
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "E") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                        Case "HbA1C"
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "F") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                        Case "UricAcid"
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(cursor, "G") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "C")
                    End Select
                Else
                    cursor = cursor + 1
                    GoTo X
                End If
            Else
                cursor = cursor + 1
                GoTo X
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I hope this can help someone else like me.

Note:You should set the sheet2's cell MESDATE as Text before run this program. Otherwise it will change the sheet1's cell MSEDATE to Date type.

Answer (score 0):

Use Text to column option in excel.

1) Copy Data to Excel

2) Select data

3) Under Data Ribbon -> Select Text to Column

4) Choose option Delimted and Click Next

5) Choose Delimter As Space (Check checkbox) and Click next

6) Choose destination and Press Finish

[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4OGd.png)

[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zWy2.png)

[Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWTmc.png)

[Step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIksr.png)